# Como deixar embed YouTube responsivo no site, ao abrir quero Width apareça 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Eu já tenho vários embed no meu site porém não quero ir lá e alterar 1 por 1. o que eu quero é um código para alterar todos os `Iframes`, com 100% da largura e height se ajustar de forma responsiva.

```css
.conteudo{
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  width:700px;
  height:700px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ljBNAt2gwc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: fiz isso e funcionou, só com .css
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4t0JxiBeO0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Não é possível com CSS** fazer o ajuste do vídeo, pois o vídeo esta em um Iframe, logo se usar `width:` quem ajustará é o Iframe, a única maneira que penso que funcionará é usar a [*Youtube API Iframe*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-br)

Um exemplo usando somente a API do Youtube, **sem precisar** usar bibliotecas externas inteiras como jQuery e **sem necessidade** de plugins, cada vídeo vai ter que ficar assim:

```
<div data-youtube="[ID DO VIDEO DO YOUTUBE]" id="[ID opcional, não pode repetir]"></div>

<div data-youtube="[ID DO VIDEO DO YOUTUBE]"></div> <!-- sem id -->

<div data-youtube="[ID DO VIDEO DO YOUTUBE]" id="[ID opcional, não pode repetir]"></div>
```

Então com as funções nativas do JavaScript:

- HTMLElement.dataset
- querySelectorAll
- addEventeListner para usar com resize da Janela

Eu criei este exemplo:

> O `id=""` agora é opcional, se não tiver id será gerado um id neste formato: `id="youtube-responsive-x"` (o `x` será um numero)

```
<!-- sem id -->
<div data-youtube="M7lc1UVf-VE"></div>

<hr>

<!-- com id -->
<div data-youtube="TALH8SsQJp4" id="baz"></div>

<script>
(function (w, d) {
    var iframes = [], genericIds = 0;

    function responsiveIframe(element)
    {
        var originalWidth = element.dataset.youtubeWidth || element.clientWidth;
        var originalHeight = element.dataset.youtubeHeight || element.clientHeight;

        element.dataset.youtubeWidth = originalWidth;
        element.dataset.youtubeHeight = originalHeight;

        element.width = "100%";

        if (originalWidth != originalHeight) {
            element.height = element.clientWidth / (originalWidth / originalHeight);
        } else {
            element.height = element.clientWidth;
        }
    }

    function putPlayer(youtubeId, elementId)
    {
        var player = new YT.Player(elementId, {
            videoId: youtubeId,
            events: {
                onReady: function() {
                    var el = d.getElementById(elementId);
                    responsiveIframe(el);
                    iframes.push(el);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    w.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function ()
    {
        //Busca todos elementos com o atributo data-youtube (tem que ter "id")
        var els = d.querySelectorAll("[data-youtube]");

        for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
            var el = els[i];

            if (!el.id) {
                genericIds++; //Incrementa para usar nos elementos sem ID
                el.id = "youtube-responsive-" + genericIds;
            }

            putPlayer(el.dataset.youtube, el.id);
        }

        w.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            if (iframes.length) {
                for (var i = 0, j = iframes.length; i < j; i++) {
                    responsiveIframe(iframes[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    //Injeta a API do Youtube
    var tag = d.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
})(window, document);
</script>
```

> Exemplo no [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnuq8r2f/)
>
> **Nota:** Não usei o Stack Snippet porque ele usa Sandbox e a API do Youtube não funciona em Sandbox

Comment: nesse caso toda vida que eu for posta um artigo com vídeo, vou ter que colocar uma div com uma id diferente?

Comment: Por favor cara pode fazer, preciso muito da sua ajuda

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente,  porém com a questão da API do Youtube na div, teria como eu colocar os atributos do Embed, poque eu não quero que apareça, vídeos relacionados ao acabar meu vídeo, ou o título do vídeo pois pode a pessoa clicar e sair do meu site, e meu interesse é ela navegar. Pode resolver mais essa questão gênio @guilhermeNascimento

Comment: Aconteceu algo, não que seja um problema, o script até funciona, Responsivo e tals, porém se abrir ele na tela do celular não fica responsivo e sim só na tela do computador, veja -
http://maroclub.net/cardapio-completo-para-perder-6kg-em-15-dias/ nesse link você abre e pode até diminuir a tela q ele ficará responsivo, mas se abrir direto na resolução do celular ele não se ajusta

Comment: Moto G, android 6.0, também testei no pc, diminuindo a janela no google chrome e em seguida atualizando.

Comment: Olhou? caso esteja tentando me avisa

Comment: @GersonValdeir funcionou no Browser (nativo) e Chrome e funcionou normalmente em ambos, você abriu o jsfiddle no seu celular, ou vc criou uma página, se criou uma página pode ser outro script seu que conflitou com este.

Comment: Eu uso a plataforma wordpress, pode me ajudar ? preciso muito ajeitar meus iframes para responsivo, http://maroclub.net

Comment: Sim é, é possível fazer isso sim

Comment: Só não alterar nome de divs ou outros elementos pois posso acabar com o site inteiro, entaão oque posso é implementar, tanto js, css ou html

Comment: Não isso eu sei, entendo o básico, sei que funciona no funciona YouTube

Comment: @GersonValdeir a parte do vars, pra tirar o relacionados  estou resolvendo, assim que possivel lhe envio.

Comment: ok você é o cara, me ajudando bastante

Comment: @GersonValdeir testa isso e veja se funciona no seu android: https://github.com/brcontainer/responsive-youtube.js

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67573/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-como-deixar-embed-youtube-responsiv)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Esse exemplo usa com o seu código ?

Comment: @GersonValdeir esse link que lhe mandei era o mesmo código da pergunta, mas melhorado, o link é meu a lib também, pode usar tranquilamente, se falhar algo me avise. Só tem uma pequena diferença, essa nova que eu fiz (no link) tem retrocompatibilidade com alguns navegadores mais antigos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tentei mas não consegui, poderia por favor colocar o exemplo, atualizado e completo em uma outra resposta se não for incomodo!

Comment: @GersonValdeir então está um pouco corrido pra mim, mas vou criar um exemplo online e te mando o link assim que puder, então é só abrir o link no celular.

Comment: Cara sei nem como te agradecer aguardarei....

Answer (score 4):

Da uma olhada nessa biblioteca javascript/Jquery, ela é usada para videos responsivos:

http://fitvidsjs.com/

https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js

So procurar sobre fitvids.

Para o video 100% adiciona no css um seletor avançado "iframe[src*="youtube".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
   $(".conteudo").fitVids();
});
```

```css
.conteudo{
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
iframe[src*="youtube"] {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitvids/1.2.0/jquery.fitvids.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ljBNAt2gwc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Coloquei mas não funcionou, Colocar no <head> pode não funcionar ? tanto o jQuery como o Css não funcionaram

Comment: normalmente scripts como o fitvids eu coloco no footer, na parte de baixo, no exemplo a cima, mas pode colocar no head, so ira funcionar os iframes que estiverem dentro da div com a class "conteudo".

Comment: Eu trabalho com o WordPress, Abri área de posts do site para procurar com Inspecionar elemento, Porém existe várias divs e coloquei algumas mas não funcionou. pode me da uma mãosinha, abra o site e olhe o a área de poste, no inspecionar  Elemento, olhe se consegue identificar div com class do conteúdo.

Comment: joga esse código $( '.entry-content' ).fitVids(); em vez de $(".conteudo").fitVids();

Comment: Já tentei essa class também mas não funcionou :´(

Comment: Se você observar o wordpress deixa o <iframe> Dentro uma outra tag, <p> adiciona automático, será que precisa referenciar ela também ?

Comment: não precisa, fitvids já foi aplicado, só falta deixar o width 100%, e setar um heigth, que no caso terá que ser manual, ou você pode usar o exemplo a baixo, ele adaptou o iframe de uma forma bem legal

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando a biblioteca fitVids, você deve selecionar via jquery o elemento pai do iframe que será responsivo.

Na documentação é possível obter mais detalhes de utilização, como ignorar alguns elementos ou selecionar elementos específicos: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js

No seu código você deve importar a biblioteca do FitVids.js e adicionar uma linha de código.

```js
$(".conteudo").fitVids();
```

```css
.conteudo{
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  width:700px;
  height:700px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitvids/1.2.0/jquery.fitvids.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ljBNAt2gwc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Existem duas formas de fazer isso com CSS.**

Uma é fazendo o `iframe` do Youtube ocupar a tela inteira, a outra e usar um *hake* com `padding` para fazer o `iframe` manter o *aspect-ratio*.

Colocando o iframe com 100% de altura e largura, sem distorcer o vídeo, ou deixar faixas pretas na lateral. Para isso foi preciso usar `@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9)` e `@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9)` para controlar o comportamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
iframe {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
 height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  iframe {
    width: auto;
 height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WHPEKLQID4U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Opção mantendo o aspect-ratio com o *hake* do `padding`**

O `padding` do elemento é relativo a largura dele, e pode ser usado em porcentagem, com isso a gente pode ter um `.box` com 100% de largura e um `padding-top` que vai "forçar" a altura do box para manter uma medida de *aspect-ratio*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber o valor desse `padding-top` a gente tem que saber a proporção do vídeo. Por padrão o Youtube costuma usar `9/16`. Então pegamos 9 dividimos por 16 e multiplicamos por 100 e teremos o valor de `56,25%` que é nosso *aspect-ratio* que vamos usar no valor do `padding`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vc tiver um vídeo `3 / 4 = 0,75` > `* 100 = 75%`. Então no css vc coloca no `.box` o `padding-top: 75%`  e assim vc vai manter o *aspect-ratio* do vídeo. Com essa técnica vc precisa de um elemento para colocar o vídeo dentro, não da para aplicar direto no `iframe`, pois nesse casso o `iframe` vai ter 100% do tamanho do `.box`, que por sua vez é o *container* que vai manter o aspecto do vídeo que está dentro dele.

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.box {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 56.25%;
 position: relative;
}
.box iframe {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WHPEKLQID4U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

---

**DICA**

Leitura recomendada para entender o *aspect-ratio*:
 https://mdooh.progic.com.br/aspect-ratio/

Calculadora de *aspect-ratio*:
 https://calculateaspectratio.com/

Documentação da Mozilla sobre *aspect-ratio*:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio