# Precisa de uma ajuda com videos html

Tags: html, html5

Como faço pra colocar esses 3 video um do lado do outro com legenda em baixo??
codigo:

```
<section id="projetos">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="font-weight-bold" style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 29px; margin-bottom: 15px;">Projetos</div>
            <video  width="320" height="240" controls style="margin-right: 30px;">
                <source src="videos/video01.mp4" type="video/mp4">

            </video>
            <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
            <video width="320" height="240" controls style="margin-right: 30px;">
                <source src="videos/video02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
            <video width="320" height="240" controls style="margin-right: 30px;">
                <source src="videos/video03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>




        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara sobre a responsividade do vídeo de uma olhada nessa resposta que vai te ajudar! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246495/como-deixar-embed-youtube-responsivo-no-site-ao-abrir-quero-width-apare%C3%A7a-100/369847#369847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não indico o use de `float` por diversos motivos, mas principalmente pq pode ser que seu *layout* quebre e vc precise fazer um `clearfix`.

Eu sugiro o `flex`, assim os itens se organizam de forma mais responsiva como vc pode ver...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima. Repare que eu separei cada grupo de elementos dentro de um container.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.videos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="projetos">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="font-weight-bold" style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 29px; margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;">Projetos</div>
    <div class="videos">
      <div class="box">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/video01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/video02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/video03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inserir uma div com `float: left` para cada vídeo, embora existam vários outros modos de fazer isso por exemplo com `display: flex` (que é utilizado pelo bootstrap).

```
<section id="projetos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="font-weight-bold" style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 29px; margin-bottom: 15px;">Projetos</div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <video  width="320" height="240" controls style="margin-right: 30px;">
                <source src="videos/video01.mp4" type="video/mp4">

            </video>
            <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls style="margin-right: 30px;">
            <source src="videos/video02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">                       
            <video width="320" height="240" controls style="margin-right: 30px;">
                <source src="videos/video03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <p><strong>Descriçao:</strong>Altomaçao.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```